Can I use an event listener with two events?
I am doing a "pixel art" web page, and I don't want the "pencil" to draw when I am not pressing the button on the mouse, I try to do this but either I can make the "pencil" work with the click or with the mouseover. In conclusion I want to click and keep dragging the mouse to draw with the click pressed down.
What is doing my code right now is working with the mouseover without pressing down. Hope you can help me


const GRIDSIDE = 600;
let side = 16;

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);

    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;
    gridElement.style.height = ${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px;

    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown", addColor);
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseover", addColor);     
}

function addColor() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}

.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




This question is similar to: how we can add two event listeners click and keydown in javascript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Louys Patrice Please don't edit a question and correct syntax errors in the OPs code. The OP needs to be aware of those errors as well as others who come along and read the question. As you can see in my answer, I've pointed out the error.

@ScottMarcus: Got it. I thought I could help OP (new user with rep 1) with this bening fix, which was not changing the question itself... But ok.

First, your template literals don't have the back ticks around them.
Now, there may be a more concise way to do this, but it seems to me that you need 3 events: one to initiate the highlighting, one to continue highlighting as you move the mouse, and one to cancel the highlighting.
See comments inline:


const GRIDSIDE = 600;
let side = 16;

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");
let active = false;

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);

    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;
    gridElement.style.height = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;

    // Start a new highlighting session when a click happens
    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown", begin);
    
    // Continue highlighting while mouse moves
    gridElement.addEventListener("mousemove", addColor);
    
    // Stop highlighting session
    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseup", stop);      
}

function begin() {
  active = true;
  this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

function addColor() {
  if (active)  {
    this.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  }
}

function stop() {
  active = false;
}
body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}

.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Etch-A-Sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>




You can also take out of the creating div loop the eventListeners for each div and check for event.target that has .gridElement class


const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
const GRIDSIDE = 600
let side = 16
let isDrawing = false


function createElem(elem1,elem2){
     function addElem (){
        let gridElement = document.createElement(elem1)
        gridElement.className = 'gridElement'
        gridElement.style.width = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;
        gridElement.style.height = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;
        elem2.appendChild(gridElement)
    }
    return addElem()
}

function colorIt(){
    this.style.background = 'blue'
}

function GetSignal(event){
    if(event.target.matches('.gridElement') && isDrawing){
        colorIt.call(event.target,event)
    }
}


for(let i=0;i<side*side;i++){
    createElem('div', grid)
}

grid.addEventListener('mousedown',function(event){
    isDrawing = true
    GetSignal(event)
})

grid.addEventListener('mouseup',function(event){
    isDrawing = false
})

grid.addEventListener('mouseover',function(event){
    GetSignal(event)
})
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: aliceblue;
}

    
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 100px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;

    box-shadow: 10px 10px #D6EAF8;
}


.gridElement {
    flex: none;
    border: 1px solid whitesmoke;
}
<div class="grid"></div>




You can add event listeners for mousedown, mouseup, and mouseover to handle a drawing logic and then track the mouse state with the variable.
const GRIDSIDE = 600;
let side = 16;
let isDrawing = false; // Track mouse state

const grid = document.querySelector(".grid");

for (let i = 0; i < (side * side); i++) {
    const gridElement = document.createElement("div");
    grid.appendChild(gridElement);

    gridElement.classList.add("gridElement");
    gridElement.style.width = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;
    gridElement.style.height = `${(GRIDSIDE / side) - 2}px`;

    gridElement.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => {
        isDrawing = true;
        addColor(e);
    });

    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseover", (e) => {
        if (isDrawing) addColor(e);
    });

    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        isDrawing = false;
    });

    gridElement.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        isDrawing = false;
    });
}

function addColor(e) {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}

// Make sure to reset isDrawing state on mouseup anywhere on the document
document.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
    isDrawing = false;
});

